# Critical update error now showing up

Tags: apex, critical-update, abstract

Recently, Salesforce came out with a critical update to [Restrict Reflective Access to Non-Global Constructors in Packages](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_apex_publicConstructorsInMgdPackages.htm). The update is active in my org. My code uses `Type.newInstance`. I'm a bit confused as to why my code is not throwing the error as per the description provided by the critical update.

This is the code structure I have :

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
  //some methods + abstract methods
}

public class IWillExtendAbstractClass extends AbstractClass {
  //all abstract methods implemented etc
}
```

Now I execute the following in anonymous window in dev console (expecting an error to show up for instantiating an abstract class)

```
AbstractClass obj = (AbstractClass) Type.forName('IWillExtendAbstractClass').newInstance();
```

I thought this line instantiated an abstract class but since it ran, I sense a gap in my understanding. Can someone explain what this line is doing and give an example for when the error message `ApexType does not have a no-arg constructor` will show up as per the details of this critical update? Where will this critical update impact the most?

Answer (score 1):

The `IWillExtendAbstractClass` implementation is not `abstract`. From the documentation:

> construction of abstract classes or interfaces is no longer allowed even when the type is visible and can be referenced using Type.forName. Such instantiation fails with this message: "ApexType does not have a no-arg constructor" where ApexType is the type you want to create using the Type.newInstance method.

You should get the above mentioned error if you try to instantiate the `abstract` class instead.

```
AbstractClass instance;

// below is not abstract
// therefore it does not match
// conditions from documentation
instance = (AbstractClass)Type.forName('IWillExtendAbstractClass').newInstance();

// below is abstract and should throw the error
instance = (AbstractClass)Type.forName('AbstractClass').newInstance();

// can save a few characters
instance = AbstractClass.class.newInstance();
```

Comment: What does this line mean? `AbstractClass obj = (AbstractClass) Type.forName('IWillExtendAbstractClass').newInstance();`